# Torrent shows a few kB upload speed while downloading, but it doesn't count the data uploaded under the 'Uploaded' counter at the specific torrent

Tags: utorrent

Why is this?
I am using uTorrent. 
Pretty much the title: when I am downloading a file and it is still being downloaded, it shows a few kB/s uploading, but the data that upload speed would have accumulated over the downloading time does not get counted, so the 'Uploaded' line is still at '0 B'.

It just bugs me, not life or death importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the overhead from uTorrent talking to trackers and other peers. That data does not contain any content from the payload in the torrent. If you look in the `Speed` tab, you'll find that what you're seeing is graphed by a dotted red line representing the overhead, while the solid red line is still at zero.

[image]